# Is there anyway to generate animated images from PowerPoint Presentations when using Microsoft Interop Services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, powerpoint, office-interop

I've a script that converts a PPT file to a folder of images (jpg/png/gif) but they're static images. I've noticed that SlideShark somehow gets animated images (some of the time) and I know for certain that they too use the Microsoft Inteorp Services.

Any help is appreciated.